# How to add rect using Skia Sharp and apply both fill color and stroke color to that object?

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, skia, skiasharp

How to add rect or any shape using Skia Sharp and apply both fill color and stroke color to that object in iOS

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To draw both fill and stroke, you will have to do two paint operations:

```
// the rectangle
var rect = SKRect.Create(10, 10, 100, 100);

// the brush (fill with blue)
var paint = new SKPaint {
    Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
    Color = SKColors.Blue
};

// draw fill
canvas.DrawRect(rect, paint);

// change the brush (stroke with red)
paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
paint.Color = SKColors.Red;

// draw stroke
canvas.DrawRect(rect, paint);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Matthew, can you help me on finding difference between drawing through UIVIew and SkiaSharp it seems both are similar.

Comment: There is no real difference as such. But the advantage of SkiaSharp is that the code is 100% re-usable on most platforms - servers to mobile, windows to linux.